# javascript: it keeps copying what it copies on the 1st click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a script that will copy the entire div and add it to the main div.

Here's the code:

script:

```
var a = 0;
function add(name) {
    if (a <= 10) {
        a++;
        var parent = name.parentNode;
        var content = parent.querySelector("div");
        var objTo = document.getElementById(content.id);
        var str = document.getElementById(parent.id).innerHTML;
        str = str.replace(/_1/gi,  '_' + a);
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.setAttribute("id", a);
        divtest.innerHTML = str + a;
        objTo.appendChild(divtest);
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div id="main">
<button onclick="add(this);return false;">show it</button>
<div id="content">
<input name="n_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="f_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="l_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="m_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="a_1" type="text" size="1">
</div>
</div>
```

as you run the code it works but the main issue is it keeps duplicating also the button being duplicate too.

OUTPUT:

> 1st OUTPUT:

```
+
test
+
test1
```

> 2nd OUTPUT:

```
+
test
+
test1
+
test
+
test1
test2
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

> 1st OUTPUT:

```
<input name="n_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="f_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="l_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="m_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="a_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="n_2" type="text" size="1">
<input name="f_2" type="text" size="1">
<input name="l_2" type="text" size="1">
<input name="m_2" type="text" size="1">
<input name="a_2" type="text" size="1">
test1
```

> 2nd OUTPUT:

```
<input name="n_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="f_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="l_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="m_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="a_1" type="text" size="1">
<input name="n_2" type="text" size="1">
<input name="f_2" type="text" size="1">
<input name="l_2" type="text" size="1">
<input name="m_2" type="text" size="1">
<input name="a_2" type="text" size="1">
<input name="n_3" type="text" size="1">
<input name="f_3" type="text" size="1">
<input name="l_3" type="text" size="1">
<input name="m_3" type="text" size="1">
<input name="a_3" type="text" size="1">
test1
test2
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(foo.id)` is the same as just `foo`. Why do you need to search for an element by ID if you already have the element itself?

Comment: Why shouldn't it copy the button? You told it to copy everything inside the DIV, and the button is inside the DIV.

Comment: it will copies what inside the div. my goal make a dynamic div by copying the 1st div

Comment: if i remove it outside the div the button wont work.

Comment: Redundant Element getting. You can't have an `id` more than once on a page anyways. Probably need to rethink your design. If you want all the code as a String inside any block level Element use `.innerHTML`.

Comment: @PHPglue No, you can't have an ID more than once on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It copies the button because that's what you tell it to do:

```
var str = document.getElementById(parent.id).innerHTML;
```

This gets the HTML of the button's parent, which of course will include the button itself.

If you only want to copy the content of "content" and append it to "main", that would be

```js
var a = 0;

function add(name) {
  if (a <= 10) {
    a++;
    var parent = name.parentNode;
    var content = parent.querySelector("div");
    var str = content.innerHTML;
    str = str.replace(/_1/gi, '_' + a);
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.setAttribute("id", a);
    divtest.innerHTML = str + a;
    parent.appendChild(divtest);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<button onclick="add(this); return false;">+</button>
<div id="content">
test 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about i have 2 main divs it will gonna add on the end of the div not on the 1st main div i selected

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... but if you keep changing your question, no one will bother to answer.

Comment: im sorry im just tired forgot to put the button inside the div on my draft html. thanks alot it really works

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code like so, and I believe this is the result you expect?

```
var a = 0;
function add(name) {
    if (a <= 10) {
        a++;
        var parent = name.parentNode;
        var content = parent.querySelector("div");
        var objTo = document.getElementById(content.id);
        var str = objTo.innerHTML;
        str = str.replace(/_1/gi,  '_' + a);
        objTo.innerHTML = str + '<div id="id-' + a + '">test' + a + '</div>';
    }
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgbfLfLu/

Comment: Hang on I realised you want to remove the last line first if it has a number... one sec..

Comment: i want to copy what inside the div but exclude the button and it should not copy what it copies 1st.

Comment: I've updated it with behavior that seems to match your EXPECTED OUTPUT in the OP.

Comment: also note I prefixed your ids with "id-" because they were numerical which is a problem.

Comment: Also the reason I changed it to adding the new content with innerHTML is that it's supposedly faster for JS to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

you can try also this way

removing last div:

```
var a = 0;
function add(name) {
    if (a <= 10) {
        a++;
        var parent = name.parentNode;
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.setAttribute("id", a);
        divtest.innerHTML = "test" + a;
        if(a>1){            
            var lastdiv = document.getElementById(a-1);
            parent.removeChild(lastdiv);
        }
        parent.appendChild(divtest);        
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oxhta38k/

without removing the last div:

```
var a = 0;

function add(name) {
    if (a <= 10) {
        a++;
        var parent = name.parentNode;
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.setAttribute("id", a);
        divtest.innerHTML = "test" + a;
        parent.appendChild(divtest);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtLq2d18/

Comment: how about it put a textbox inside the content div. it should be copy that one

Comment: so something like this would be needed: var content = parent.querySelector("div").innerHTML; var new_content = content.replace('test',  'test' + a); divtest.innerHTML = new_content; you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/pk8855ft/

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know what to say, because your code is redundant, not backward compatible and seemingly pointless. Try the following:

```
//<![CDATA[
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function C(t){
  return doc.createElement(t);
}
var add = (function(){
  var i = 0;
  return function(n){
    if(n !== undefined){
      i = n;
    }
    return ++i;
  }
})();
function ContentSpecializer(contentElement, outputElement, startNum){
  this.contentElement = contentElement || bod;
  this.initialContent = this.contentElement.innerHTML;
  this.outputElement = outputElement || bod;
  this.startNum = startNum || 0; add(this.startNum-1);
  this.addNum = function(){
    var d = C('div');
    d.innerHTML = this.initialContent+add(); this.outputElement.appendChild(d);
    return this;
  }
}
var cs = new ContentSpecializer(E('content'), E('main'));
cs.addNum().addNum().addNum().addNum().addNum();
}
//]]>
```